# localhost not working after save in VS Code

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Currently working on a project, the project works perfectly fine after npm start and can function normally. However, after any changes made in VS Code, it seems localhost not listening any changes anymore. The workaround is to refresh the browser anytime changes has been made. Does anyone have experienced above issue?

I have tried to remove package-lock.json and node_modules, re-install packages by npm install, nothing helped.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "crypto-dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://nickng852.github.io/crypto-dashboard/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.3.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.7.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.7",
    "axios": "^0.22.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.6.0",
    "firebase": "^9.1.2",
    "html-react-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "millify": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "postcss": "^7.0.38",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^3.3.0",
    "react-click-away-listener": "^2.0.5",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.16",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
```

}

Comment: Please provide `package.json` codes.

Comment: @KaungKhantZaw added in the post, thx!

Comment: Seems like you need to change version of `react-scripts` and modify `FAST_REFRESH` in .env file or in `npm run start` script according to [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9904#issuecomment-735223010)

Comment: @KaungKhantZaw Thanks, issue solved. Solution: update `react-scripts` and `postcss` to lastest version without modify `FAST_REFRESH` in .env file